# How to stop user trashing their own question

Tags: discussion

[This is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20584789/2065121)

I've rolled back once but the OP seems to want the question body to be removed.

Should I just ignore it and move on?

Comment: Flag for moderator attention. Don't get into a rollback war.

Comment: I'd only bother if there are any valuable answers

Comment: @CodesInChaos agreed, there were no answers but there was a half-useful comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given that they've now deleted it and there were no answers I'm happy to let this slide. (Although I did take a look at other activity from the user to double check)

Where self-deletion is an option and sensible it can be worth pointing it out as an option in a comment, if the OP seems to have failed to spot that option as appears to be the case here.

In general terms flagging for moderator attention is the way to go - we can warn and lock if needed, rollback wars don't often to lead to resolutions naturally. There is also a flag that gets raised automatically when rollback wars are detected, but a human comment adding some context to the automatic flag can save quite a bit of time hunting around.